# I want to execute nav tab and page scroll at same time on a link click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to execute nav tab and page scroll at same time on a link click using jquery. when i am clicking on link it open nav tab and when on again click it scroll. Here is the code.

```
$("a[data-tab-destination]").on('click', function() {
       var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab-destination');
        $("#"+tab).click();
        $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#review').offset().top }, 1600);
});
```

Comment: change this part
$("#"+tab).click(); -> $("#"+tab).trigger("click");

Comment: nothing happened tab is openning but page is not scrolling .

Comment: hmm... I tried it and worked for me. Is #review element exists?
 Can you show a little bit more from your code? Try alert or log this: $('#review').offset().top because it maybe has absolute position or something... If its 0 use another anchor :/

Comment: when i click this link two time its working fine for me .. but don't know how to do the same .. #review is id where scroll will stop .

Comment: I am curious, what happens if you swap the two events? Maybe the tab click event stop the click event of "a". So first scroll and after trigger the click.

Comment: kindly let me know the code. as i am totally confused and stuck . :( :( :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107847/discussion-between-michael-and-travelers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  $(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    
    $("a[data-tab-destination]").on('click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab-destination');
        $("a[href='#"+tab+"']").trigger("click");
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#review').offset().top }, 1600);
    });
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" data-tab-destination="tabs-2">click</a>
  
  <div style="height:2000px; width:100%;"></div>
  
  <h2 id="review">Title</h2>
  
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
      <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the full code what you ask from me

Answer (score 0):

You should `preventDefault` on click to prevent default link behavior.

Comment: i did it like this but no result

$("a[data-tab-destination]").on('click', function(event) {
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab-destination');
  $("#"+tab).click();
  $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#review').offset().top }, 1600);
  event.preventDefault();
  });